# Fiber optic transceiver for lower speeds

Tags: cables, transceiver, optics, optical-fibre

I am trying to figure out if a QSFP-DD transceiver can break out 8x 10G lanes if I make/use a 1:8 fiber optic breakout cable. It seems like most Transceivers are rated for one speed only, so if I get a QSFP-DD transceiver (such as a 400G-SR8), and break it out to 8 × 10G SFP+ transceivers, will that work? All the QSFP-DD transceivers seem to be rated for breakouts of 50G or 25G.

I tried reaching out to local vendors but they were unsure as well. I know QSFP and SFP are supposed to be backwards compatible, but that seems to be only for cables and not transceivers, so if I can use a QSFP+ to 4x SFP+ cable but then I'm losing 4 lanes of data? I may be also misunderstanding that as well.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!